# Magento URL redirection issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

my magneto installation is not directing properly from sub-folders. When I am on a page like the catalogsearch/advanced I am unable to get back up to the home page or any other main level link.

My .htaccess file is as follows,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/skin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

http://blogwall.ca

here is my temporary website link so you can view the behaviour, easiest link is the photos page.

Please let me know of any ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a problem of your header navigation links.

You currently have this :

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="home" title="Home" class="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="about" title="About  Us" class="">About  Us</a>
    </li>
    <li id="">
        <a href="audio" title="Media">Media</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="videos" title="Videos" class="">Videos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="../photo/category/view/id/4/" title="Photo" class="">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="../../../../../news" title="News" class="">News</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="../../../../../contacts" title="Contact Us" class="">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Try to correct this to have this :

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="/home" title="Home" class="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="/about" title="About  Us" class="">About  Us</a>
    </li>
    <li id="">
        <a href="/audio" title="Media">Media</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="/videos" title="Videos" class="">Videos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="/photo/category/view/id/4/" title="Photo" class="">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="/news" title="News" class="">News</a>
    </li>
    <li id="" class="">
        <a href="/contacts" title="Contact Us" class="">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This could do the trick.

Comment: Hi, Usually I would be able to do just that, but magento is suppose to be auto generating the links for me, and some of the pages that are broken are the main magento links. I don't know what is wrong that would cause all of the to miss the leading /

Comment: Solved. It was what you said, a custom edited navigation and it was missing the leading /.